# How to compare two sub queries in one sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a table `tbl_Country`, which contains columns called `ID` and `Name`. The `Name` column has multiple country names separated by comma, I want the id when I pass multiple country names to compare with `Name` column values. I am splitting the country names using a function - the sample query looks like this:

```
@country varchar(50)

SELECT *
FROM   tbl_Country
WHERE  (SELECT *
        FROM   Function(@Country)) IN (SELECT *
                                       FROM   Function(Name))

tbl_country    

ID        Name
1         'IN,US,UK,SL,NZ'
2         'IN,PK,SA'
3         'CH,JP'

parameter @country ='IN,SA'
```

i have to get

```
  ID 
   1
   2


NOTE:  The Function will split the string into a datatable
```

Comment: The question is: Do you want to retrieve the `ID`'s where `the combination` of the passed contries exists OR you are looking for all `ID`'s where `any` of the passed countries is present?

Comment: I am looking for all ID's where any of the passed countries is present

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Country C 
WHERE ',' + @country + ',' LIKE '%,' + C.Name + ',%';
```

Comment: @shah CONCAT() function not there in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM tbl_Country C
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Country C1 ON C1.Name=C.Country
```

Comment: Name is not a table it's column in tbl_Country table

Answer (score 0):

Basically, by specifying multiple values in a single column, you are violating the `1st NF`. Therefore, the following might not be a good approach but provides the solution that you are looking for:

```
  declare @country varchar(50)= 'IN,SA'
  declare @counterend int
  declare @counterstart int =1
  declare @singleCountry varchar(10)
  set @counterend = (select COUNT(*) from fnSplitStringList(@country))
  create table #temp10(
  id int
 ,name varchar(50))

 while @counterstart<= @counterend

begin

;with cte as (
select stringliteral country
, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by stringliteral) countryseq 
from fnSplitStringList(@country))
select @singleCountry = (select country FROM   cte where countryseq=@counterstart)

insert into #temp10(id, name)
select * from tbl_country t1
where not exists (select id from #temp10 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)
and name like '%' + @singleCountry +'%'

set @counterstart= @counterstart+1

end

select * from #temp10

begin drop table #temp10 end
```

How it works: It splits the passed string and ranks it. Afterwards, it loops through all the records for every single Value(country) produced and inserts them into temptable.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select a.id FROM   tbl_Country a inner join 
(SELECT country FROM   dbo.Function(@Country)) b on a.name=b.country
```